# Jquery Autofill repeated form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, autofill

I'm attempting to create autofill functionality for a set of form fields that have (potentially) the same data.  My situation is as follows: I have a form in which the user enters the contact information for people serving particular roles within a company (shareholders, officers, contractors, employees).  So, for example:

**For shareholders I have:**

```
First Name:
Last Name:
Email:
Telephone:
Street:
City:
State:
Zip:
```

**And for directors I have the same fields:**

```
First Name:
Last Name:
Email:
Telephone:
Street:
City:
State:
Zip:
```

Often, there's a lot of overlap between the two (directors are often shareholders in a company).  So if a user fills out *Don Draper at 42 Bullet Park Road in Ossining NY* as shareholder and then wants to add him as a director, I would like some kind of autofill function to offer to fill in the info when they start filling out the director functions.

I figure I can write up a JavaScript plugin from scratch if I need to but I was wondering if I might not need to reinvent the wheel.  Is there something in jquery that would take care of much of this for me?  Or is there a set of best practices for doing this?  Feel free to share.

I'm certainly not looking for anyone to write this for me, but a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

**Workarounds anticipated**
I do realize that the need for this could be avoided if I just provide fields for a generic person and then dynamically add roles (shareholder, director or whatever) on top of that person.  I prefer to structure it as I've described out above for organizational reasons.

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Are all the forms on one page? Or does someone fill out one form after another meaning they fill out a form, validate it and then a new form shows up?

Comment: @Grimbode  Hi there, thanks for the response. The forms are all on one page so the idea is that this autofill feature would be all client-side.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and made a little demo that will fill out a person if it notices the name is the same. http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/fqhrqwzt/1/ ( to validate a person.. click the checkbox when the row of inputs is filled out )

You'll be needing to create a search script client side. To be able to do this efficiently and with wasting the least amount of time possible you'll be creating a list of information relative to each person being filled out.

You'll need to initially create:

```
var persons = [];
```

You have a couple choices for the next part:

1. You could fill `persons` by creating another `{}` list where you fill the information like so: `{ first: 'john', last: 'smith' /* ... */}`
2. You could create a class Persons like so:

**Class:**

```
function Person(o){
  this.first = o.first || 'unknown';
  this.last = o.last || 'unknown';
  //rest of the attributes
}
```

**In use**

```
persons.push(new Person({
  first: 'john',
  last: 'smith'
}));
```

Then you create a: (supposing your form has a class name of '.person')

```
$('.person input').on('keyup', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var n = $this.attr('name'); //supposing the input name corresponds to the kind of input it is ( first, last, email, number, etc )
    var v = $this.val();

//now you need to loop through persons and see if you get a hit
$.each(persons, function(a, b){
        if(n === 'first' && b.first === v){
            $this.next().val(b.last);
        }else if(n === 'last' && b.last ===v){
            $this.prev().val(b.first);
        }
    });
});
```

You may not want to check everytime they press a key but when they change inputs. You would have to use an `.on('change', function(){})` event.

Unfortunately, I am unsure if there is something like this that already exists. If it does, you'd still have to adapt it to your specific requirements.

Keep in mind you could also create `getters` and `setters` with js classes.

```
Person.prototype.function = getFirst(){
  return this.first;
}
```